# nservicebus on-premise host using azure Queue

Tags: azure, nservicebus

It appears that all the sample projects that ship with *nServicebus* are setup where the sender and host are web roles and worker roles (and hosted via role entry point).

I have a need to do something like this:

Web Role sends message --> On Premise Host handles message

Is it possible to configure an on premise Host to use Azure Queue storage only (and not MSMQ)?

I can't seem to find a single example of this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you simply have to specify the transport when initializing the Bus:

```
   var config = Configure.With()
                 .SpringBuilder()
                 .AzureConfigurationSource() <--- Don't use this when working on premise.
                 .XmlSerializer()
                 .UnicastBus()
                 .LoadMessageHandlers()
                 .AzureQueuesTransport()  <--- Configure Azure Storage Queues
                 .IsTransactional(true)
                 .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                 .InMemorySubscriptionStorage();
```

For the documentation part, I suggest you take a look on github: https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/master/Samples/Azure

Note that most of these samples are meant to run in Windows Azure, hence the use of the **AzureConfigurationSource**. This won't work when you're running on premise since it uses settings from the RoleEnvironment. Don't use **AzureConfigurationSource** when working on premise.

Comment: I will give that a try. In regards to dependencies needed for an on Premise host, is nservicebus.azure the only one that would be needed? I notice that there is an nservicebus.hosting.azure package out there as well but i am guessing that is for when the host is seated within a worker role.

Comment: The NServiceBus.Azure package should be sufficient for what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok, i have dug into this a good bit more. Here are the conclusions i have reached. Let me know if my assumptions are incorrect.  1) i can not use the nservicebus.host.exe process  is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Thanks. I had to change the "AzureQueuesTransport()" to "AzureMessageQueue()" and it seems to work. My host is now getting a "Could not create queue error@UseDevelopmentStorage=true" but it is handling messages.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used nServiceBus but it sounds like Azure Service Bus would be your best option here for Hybrid communication between on-premises and Azure.

You could use ServiceBus Queues or be more intelligent about your model and do pub/sub via Topics and Subscriptions.

In this example you could have your Web Role write to a queue/topic and then have an on-premises consumer read from the queue/topic via a REST(.NET API). (see example in the link below)

Check out a link to the MSDN on them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh367516.aspx

Of course maybe asking Udi Dahan what is the best way forward might also be a good idea :)

Comment: Just an FYI. NServiceBus and Azure Service Bus are 2 entirely different things. NServiceBus is a framework for simplifying development of messaging based apps, while Azure Service Bus is a service that provides the infrastructure for messaging. So the two go hand in hand, and in fact nservicebus supports Azure Service Bus queues (not topics) out of the box.

Comment: I know what they are, just hadnt used NServiceBus before!