# local NServicebus Post to an Azure queue

Tags: configuration, azure, nservicebus

We have an on premises web app that uses NServicebus and we want to move the queues to azure (as part of a larger migration path to entirely cloud based).  I am trying to work up a POC but can’t seem to get it working.

I have the following configuration:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
     <section name="AzureQueueConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AzureQueueConfig, NServiceBus.Azure"/>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
</configSections>

<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
<AzureQueueConfig QueueName="timeoutmanager" 
                ConnectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<My storage account>;AccountKey=<My primary access key>"/>

<UnicastBusConfig TimeoutManagerAddress="timeoutmanager">
<MessageEndpointMappings>
  <add Messages="TechFu.Services.Bus.Messages.Publishing.CMS.SitePagePublishMessage, TechFu.Services.Bus.Messages" Endpoint="sitepagepublish" />
</MessageEndpointMappings>
```

In my application I have the bus configures as:

```
Configure.WithWeb()
.StructureMapBuilder()
.InMemorySubscriptionStorage()
       .AzureMessageQueue()
        .JsonSerializer()
.UnicastBus()
        .LoadMessageHandlers()
              .IsTransactional(true)
.CreateBus()
       .Start();
```

When I try posting to the queue, I get the following message:

```
The destination queue 'sitepagepublish@ DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=&lt;My storage account&gt;;AccountKey=&lt;My primary access key&gt;’ could not be found. You may have misconfigured the destination for this kind of message (TechFu.Services.Bus.Messages.Publishing.CMS.SitePagePublishMessage) in the MessageEndpointMappings of the UnicastBusConfig section in your configuration file. It may also be the case that the given queue just hasn't been created yet, or has been deleted.
```

I’m at a bit of a loss, I’ve tried several different samples I’ve found on the web, but I feel like my lack of azure knowledge is getting in the way.  I pulled the majority of the configuration from this question: [nservicebus on-premise host using azure Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274301/nservicebus-on-premise-host-using-azure-queue)  Is there some magic that I’m missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the destination queue exist? NServiceBus only creates source queues by default so if the destination does not exist it won't create it for you.

Comment: Yes, that was rather dumb of me.  A friend showed me the Azure Storage Explorer  http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/  after I showed him your comment and then it all made sense.  What a horribly unintuitive interface the azure management panel is - FTP would have been friendlier...

Comment: Yeah, you need a tool like that to manage your account. For servicebus queues it's a bit better, you can create those in the portal (but can't look inside them)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work because the subscription messages can't be exchanged between both of the hosts.

Better use Gateway concept of NServiceBus which will distribute messages across different sites.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try removing any reference to **MsmqTransportConfig** from your configuration file? (when using Azure queues you are actually replacing the MSMQ transport)

Comment: No difference, but I will update the question to reflect using MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig instead of MsmqTransportConfig

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with NServicebus. But Windows Azure has a built-in Service Bus, and it can integrate with queue naturally. You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_ServiceBusMessaging for a tutorial.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: In the future we may go this route, but we have a whole infrastructure that uses an on premises NSB bus, we can't drop that at this time.

Comment: Just an FYI... NServiceBus comes with both azure storage queue support as well as Service Bus queue support out of the box...

Comment: I'm happy to use the Service Bus queues; I just don't see any code samples or docs on the way to handle it.  Is there a good reference that I'm missing somewhere?  I want to host the NSB processes on site, it looked like all the samples were geared toward worker processes.